# How do I disable IVTV?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, video-capture-card, ivtv

I'm trying to debug IVTV and for this purpose I would like to know how to disable it. Since the IVTV site is down I can't find any documentation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

With the following link you will find the archived website for www.ivtv.org : http://web.archive.org/web/20120716193153/http://ivtvdriver.org/index.php/Main_Page.